# Openfire plugin CallbackOnOffline Not sending call to the web server

Tags: openfire

I'm trying to use **CallbackOnOffline** OpenFire plugin to send calls for offline users.
But my web server where I need to receive calls didn't receive it (checked on log)

This is a debug log of plugin:

> 2018.03.08 17:38:28 com.fotsum.CallbackOnOffline - intercepted message from cm2@jabber2.XX.kz to cm1@jabber2.XX.kz, recipient is available
>   false 
>   2018.03.08 17:38:28 com.fotsum.CallbackOnOffline - sending request to url='JerseyWebTarget { http://web.XX.kz }'

If I touch this web from the OpenFire server by lynx it's working and I see the call on web server log.

openfire version 4.2.2
CallbackOnOffline version 1.2
OS Debian 8 with Java JRE version 8

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I have encountered the same problem almost at the same time of this post.
Do you see the debug log after sending request to? If you see

> com.fotsum.CallbackOnOffline - can't get response status
>   url='JerseyWebTarget { https://xxx.xxx.xx/xxxx }' 
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException:
>   MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/json,
>   type=class com.fotsum.MessageData, genericType=class
>   com.fotsum.MessageData.

just like me, maybe I could help.
I resolve this by use maven to build CallbackOnOffline plugin manually.

```
# git clone https://github.com/igniterealtime/Openfire.git
# cd Openfire/src/plugins/callbackOnOffline
# mvn package
```

Then the callbackOnOffline.jar located at ./target directory. Upload to your openfire server by admin console and it will work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I haven't error which you posted. Only two lines in my log wich i posed above i see in debug log

Comment: Thankyou! I haven't this error but your solution help me! thank you very much!

Comment: Thank you! Not sure why but your solution help me too!  In my case, build the jar via Ant doesn't help.  And I spent a lot of time checking why httppost not working, because switched to httpget will work.